# C Bubble Sort algorithm

Tags: c

I have the following code which sorts the strings using bubble sort logic. The part that I am confused about is the for loop which Im not sure why i is set to one and why J is iterated until it is less than n-j:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
    char name[25][50],temp[25];
    int n, i, j;
    printf("\n\nSorts the strings of an array using bubble sort :\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Input number of strings :");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Input string %d :\n",n);
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        fgets(name[i], sizeof name, stdin);
    }

    /*Logic Bubble Sort*/
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=n-i; j++)
        {
           if (strcmp(name[j],name[j+1])>0)
           {
               strcpy(temp,name[j]);
               strcpy(name[j],name[j+1]);
               strcpy(name[j+1],temp);
           }
        }
    }
    printf("The strings appears after sorting :\n");
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
        printf("%s\n",name[i]);
}
```

Comment: Compare the steps of the algorithm with the code. You will see the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few subtle things wrong with this code

1. You are running the for loop one more than necessary.

   ```
   for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
   {
       fgets(name[i], sizeof name, stdin);
   }
   ```

The reason that is the line above `scanf("%d",&n);`

Here the end of line remains in the input stream and is being added to `name[0]`. You should change it to `scanf("%d ",&n);`

This will consume the end of line in the same statement. Also the for loop should now run from `for(i=0;i< n;i++)`.

Additionally, the `fgets` function receives a size of `name` which is too large.
It should receive a size of `name[0]`  i.e. `fgets(name[i], sizeof name[0], stdin);`

2. Now, your strings are being stored from `name[0]` to `name[n-1]` and the rest of your sort algorithm can be fixed.

   ```
   for(i=0;i< n;i++){
       for(j=0;j< n-i;j++)
       {
           if(strcmp(name[j],name[j+1])>0)
           {
               strcpy(temp,name[j]);
               strcpy(name[j],name[j+1]);
               strcpy(name[j+1],temp);
           }
       }
   }
   printf("The strings appears after sorting :\n");
   for(i=0;i< n;i++)
       printf("%s",name[i]);
   ```

The reason for the inner for loop going from 0 to `n-i` is that at the end of 1 outer loop the largest element is in `names[n-1]`

After 2 outer loops, 2 elements are sorted `[n-2]` and `[n-1]`. So there is no need to check these elements.

And so on.

Comment: Advice "you should change it to scanf("%d ",&n);" is a problem as that does not return until non-white-space is entered after the `int`.  This will oblige the user to enter an input string before seeing `printf("Input string %d :\n",n);`.

Comment: @chux - Yes, I saw that while testing, but the strings are being stored in the buffer properly. Do you have any better suggestions?

Comment: Either 1) use `fgets()` for all input or 2) code `scanf("%d",&n);` (no space in format) and then use `fgetc()` to read the rest of the line.

Comment: Would you just elaborate more on this statement? "Here the end of line remains in the input stream and is being added to name[0]. You should change it to scanf("%d ",&n);"

Comment: @user3314399 Wheh you read an integer with `scanf`, say 5, on the keyboard you press '5' then 'Enter' key. The '5' is read with `scanf` but the enter key `\n` remains in the input buffer `stdin` The next read with `fgets` reads just the first `\n` and reads a blank line.